# Can't load correct ressource when I change the CurrentUICulture

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, globalization, resx

I'm working on a WPF Application. When the main Window is initialized I get the system language of the user and change the CurrentCulture :

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
```

I have 3 .resx files (resource.fr-BE.resx, resource.nl-BE.resx, resource.resx) in a Ressources folder.

In my XAML, I refer to the default **ressource.resx** :

```
xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Renoir.UserInterface.Resources"
```

And user the key in my resource file for my controls :

Title="{x:Static r:resource.MAINWINDOW_TITLE}"

But the app can't load the correct resource file (for exemple when I change the Culture  for french (**fr-BE**), it doesn't load the **resource.fr-BE.resx** file, it always show the string in the default resource file (**resource.resx**)

But in code behind, if after I changed the CurrentCulture, I try to get a string form resx, I received the correct string :

```
ResourceManager rm = null;
            rm = new ResourceManager("Renoir.UserInterface.Resources.resource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            MessageBox.Show(rm.GetString("DATAGRID_AUTHOR"));
```

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: When do you change CultureInfo? Before or after InitializeComponent()?

Comment: Don't put "solved" in the title, marking an answer as accepted already shows everyone your problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change culture info after initializing of your window.
You need to change culture info in app.xaml.cs before initialization of your window

```
public partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Valera, I tried your solution but unfortunatley I have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it works and so I think I found the solution. In code behind, after windows is initialiized (thanks to Valera) I change the culture info of the app bu using the language code of the system of user.

And to use the right resource file, I have to precise it like this :

```
Renoir.UserInterface.Resources.Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo("nl-BE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following in the window class.

```
this.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.IetfLanguageTag)
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks I will try also your solution but for now, my solution works perfectly !